# How do I change which form is displayed in an HTML form on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to make it so that when I hit a calculate button on my input form, it automatically changes the display to the summary form. Right now, I have a functioning selector button that I can use to pan between each of the forms. I still want to be able to pan between the three forms, I just want it to take me to Summary when the calculate button is clicked. Would someone be able to help me come up with something to add to my perform calculation function to add this capability? (Please no jquery). Right now my code looks as follows:

HTML:

```
<select id="form-selector">
  <option value="_" selected disabled>pick one !</option>
  <option value="Input">Input</option>
  <option value="Output">Output</option>
  <option value="Summary">Summary</option>
</select>

<div id="my-forms">
  <form name="Input">
    <!-- All of the input boxes and a "Calculate" button -->
    <h4> form Input</h4>
  </form>
  <form name="Output">
    <!-- All of the output boxes -->
    <h4> form Output</h4>
  </form>
  <form name="Summary">
    <!-- A few more output boxes -->
    <h4> form Summary</h4>
  </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript: There is also a perform calculation function that performs all of the calculations when the calculate button is clicked.

JavaScript:

```
const formSelect = document.getElementById('form-selector'),   
myForms    = document.getElementById('my-forms');
formSelect.oninput=()=>{ myForms.className = `f-${formSelect.value}` }
```

CSS:

```
#my-forms form { display:none }
#my-forms.f-Input form[name=Input],
#my-forms.f-Output form[name=Output],
#my-forms.f-Summary form[name=Summary] { display:block }
```

Comment: not clear or try using snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```js
const myForms = document.getElementById('my-forms');
document.getElementById('form-selector').oninput=ev=>
  myForms.className = `f-${ev.target.value}`;
document.querySelector('button').onclick=ev=>
  (myForms.className = "f-Summary",false)
```

```css
#my-forms form { display:none }
#my-forms.f-Input form[name=Input],
#my-forms.f-Output form[name=Output],
#my-forms.f-Summary form[name=Summary] { display:block }
```

```html
<select id="form-selector">
  <option value="_" selected disabled>pick one !</option>
  <option value="Input">Input</option>
  <option value="Output">Output</option>
  <option value="Summary">Summary</option>
</select>

<div id="my-forms">
  <form name="Input">
    <!-- All of the input boxes and a "Calculate" button -->
    <h4> form Input</h4>
    <button>calculate</button>
  </form>
  <form name="Output">
    <!-- All of the output boxes -->
    <h4> form Output</h4>
  </form>
  <form name="Summary">
    <!-- A few more output boxes -->
    <h4> form Summary</h4>
  </form>
</div>
```

The `.oninput` event handler takes care of the `<select>` element, the `.onclick` event handler takes over when the button is clicked: It sets the class of the #my-forms div-element to "f-Summary" leading to the summary-form being displayed inside it.

Comment: I think this solution is along the right lines, but in my IDE, the ".value" is given the warning "unresolved variable value" and the second usage of "=ev=>" shows up as an unused parameter. Any idea what's going wrong?